# how to encrypt text in python using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, password-encryption

I want to encrypt a piece of text, like if someone where to type in their password it would come up with stars or the dots I'm using tkinter if that matters. in the entry part can the users password be encrypted?

```
w2 = Label(root, text="Password")
w2.pack()

e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
e1 = Entry( root, show= '*', textvariable = passport )
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is:

```
w2 = Label(root, text="Password")
w2.pack()

e1 = Entry(root,show="*")
e1.pack()
```

This will show a * instead of other characters.
Then maybe add:

```
if e1 == "PASSWORD HERE" :
    #What happens if the password is correct
else:
    #What happens if the password is incorrect
```